vector of random variable with density
Let $X_i\colon \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ ($i=1\ldots,n$) be independent real random variable on the same probability space $\Omega$.
I consider the vector $X\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$,
$\omega\mapsto \big(  X_1(\omega),\ldots,X_n(\omega) \big)$
I suppose that $X_i$ has density $f_i\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.
I want to know the density of $X$.
Or, at least I want to know if it is true that, for every measurable $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ P(X\in A) = \int_A\prod_if(x_i)dx. $$
QUESTIONS:

How to prove that $x\mapsto \prod_if(x_i)$ is a density for $X$ ? (is it true ?)

How to prove $ P(X\in A) = \int_A\prod_if(x_i)dx. $?  (is it true ?)



EDIT : full proof here : https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/lefrido.pdf (in French). Search for the label PROPooCXSWooByucuN

Use the independence and think about special cases of $A$ for which it is obviously true.
